# Why isnt this value imaginary? Or is it?

Tags: roots

Lets suppose we have a square, 50m², and another square, 25m². Subtracting the second from the first we get:

$$50\textrm{m}^2 - 25\textrm{m}^2 = 25\textrm{m}^2$$

something that makes absolute sense, so why cant we say that 5m could make up a negative square? I.e. $-25\textrm{m}^2$, as in $50\textrm{m}^2$ and ($-25\textrm{m}^2$)

Obviously two negative "real" numbers cant be multiplied to be a negative number, but in practice, we can have negative squares, is $-25\textrm{m}^2$ only imaginary? Since both its sides would be negative compared to a normal square.

Maybe its a silly question, but why cant negative squares exist, when they are just as "real" as negative integers, i.e. $50+(-25)$, or even $-1$, a value we can only assume to be real (as it would make no sense to take a negative amount from say a stack of well anything).

edit: Is this really a bad question?

Comment: A multiplicative value that together with a real number defines a negative square..? Or am I misunderstanding the imaginary value-definition

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the sign on the area isn't indicating an area. The sign on $-25m^2$ is indicative of a procedure where you are removing area.

On the other hand there is a notion of "net signed area." This is comparing area above or below a separating line by attaching a sign to one or the other.

So negative are isn't imaginary, so to speak, it is merely an assignment of measure.

Comment: The square we are making, is a mirror of the original, but half. Its x-axis is negative (1/2) same as its y side. It would likewise, have an area that is negative, and (1/2)^2 of the original squares sides. Doesnt this mean I can construct a negative square: (-x/2)^2=-y ? or, (-x/2*-y/2)=-z, where "-" denotes a value being less than 0. Or does it say somewhere that squares cant be negative? Isn't even -1 imaginary? To a certain degree

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give several points of view as to why constructing a square with "negative sides" (that is, a square with negative coordinates) and assigning it a negative area isn't a good idea.

And then restore your faith in your system, because someone has already thought up something similar.

---

From a number theory point of view, we're essentially answering the following question:

**Why can't we have $(-x)(-x)=-x^2$?**

The answer can range from very simple to very complicated. To begin with, we should generalize the square to a rectangle. So our question becomes:

**Why can't we have $(-x)(-y)=-xy$?**

I think you can begin to see the problems here. First of all, you no longer have a "number $1$", which you could multiply with any number and give that number. Because $(-1)\times1=-1 \neq1$. So multiplication between the natural numbers can't be easily extended to the negative numbers.

You also have problems when solving equations. The equation $(-2)x=-4$ have two solutions, $x=2$ and $x=-2$. This might not seem important, but this means that the function $f(x)=(-2)x$ don't have an inverse anymore, but $g(x)=2x$ has.

And I won't even mention how problematic the Pythagorean Theorem becomes.

---

From a geometric point of view, you create a problem with reference systems.

The negative area is dependent on the origin. But you could put the origin in the corner of a room, while I put it in the center of the Earth. Thus, you might have a negative area, while I have a positive one. Imagine what happens when trying to sum the areas.

Also, the sign of the area becomes dependent on the direction you measure its length.

---

That said, not all hope is lost in your system: There is actually a way to have your square with "negative area" using vectors.

But they rely on entirely different concepts and rigorous proofs (for example, by agreeing upon a direction of measure and position of origin) than just making up a new multiplication rule for all numbers.

And yes, it still respects the old rule $(-x)(-x)=x^2$.

Comment: Both sides of the square I'm subtracting, is negative compared to the original, as it mirrors the former. It will be, relatively, -(1/2) in the x-axis, and -(1/2) in the y-axis. Compared to the original it will be a negative square. Doesnt this suggest you could make a negative square with -x^2? Maybe I'm just silly

Comment: Let me see if I understood it right. You're building a  square with side $-\frac{1}{2}$ and area $1$? Or is it a square with side 1 whose side  "begins" at $-\frac{1}{2}$ and ends at $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Again, very informally speaking.

Comment: also, If I had to defend a stance like the one I'm asking here, I would argue, as reply to you square of "posive integers" part, that 2^2 doesnt actually have to be 2+2, it might as well be -2+-2, and, that by omitting that, you introduce an error to your calculations, or algebraic bag-of-tricks

Comment: Well, your second part is true in the usual system, but then $(-2)+(-2)=2\times (-2)$.

Comment: the square is -1/2 x times -1/2 y, with the area -25m^2. Im arguing this is easily imaginable. A square with a negative sum.

Comment: if you were to take -2 twice, you would get the same, sure. Am I unwillingingly arguing -2*-2 could be -4 here? I was not intending to do so, I just happened to imagine a negative square, if that makes sense

Comment: I'll edit my answer then to accomodate it (and delete the rest, since you seem to understand the basic concepts I wrote there)

Comment: Check the new answer. Also, if this addresses what you wanted to ask, I'd like to ask you to be clearer in your question next time. ;)

Comment: I'll give you a mark for effort, but I dont see the answer. I think the problem comes from how we understand multiplicative values, and confuse them with additive ones. I feel negative squares can exist, just as much as negative integers can. Addition is one thing, ratios another, and even further, squares/roots. What I'm saying, I can certainly imagine negative squares

Comment: The way you're thinking about it is formalized in Analytical Geometry and Linear Algebra, so if you're interested in it you may want to study those subjects. They're undergraduate-level, though.